# Prove $1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots n^3 = \frac{n^2(n + 1)^2}{4}$ with mathematical induction

Tags: induction

Hello guys I'm trying to prove this equation with mathematical induction method.

So for n = 1 I know that :

1 = 1

Now I know that it works for some k

I wanna prove it for k + 1:

Since :

I can rewrite it as :

So I'm stuck here.. I don't know what should I do.. Should I first square (k + 1)^2 or rewrite (k + 1)^3 ??'
Either way I get weird result and don't know how to proceed with this next step to prove mathematical
induction. I mean I can multiple k^2 with the first parenthesis but I think I should leave it that way and do smth other than that. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Math SE, as images are not searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there! Notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2}}{4} + (k+1)^{3} & = \frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2}+4(k+1)^{3}}{4}\\\\
& = \frac{(k^{2}+4(k+1))(k+1)^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \frac{(k^{2} + 4k + 4)(k+1)^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \frac{(k+2)^{2}(k+1)^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \frac{(k+1)^{2}(k+2)^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \frac{(k+1)^{2}((k+1)+1)^{2}}{4}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Omg thank you.. how on earth did I miss it. That way it looks easy to solve but I had to complicate unnecesarily. This deserves best answer :)

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Note:  It's enough to prove $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac {(n-1)^2n^2}4 = n^3$.

That is to say, if we assume Equation 1: $1^3 + 2^3 + ...... + (n-1)^3=  \frac {(n-1)^2n^2}4$

And we want to prove Equation 2: $1^3 + 2^3 +.... + (n-1)^3 + n^3 = \frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4$

That is a matter of proving by subtraction Equation 2 for Equation 1, that

$n^3= \frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac {(n-1)^2n^2}4$

So... Lets do that.

$\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac {(n-1)^2n^2}4=$

$\frac {n^2}4[ (n+1)^2 - (n-1)^2] =$

$\frac {n^2}4[\{(n+1)+(n-1)\}\{(n+1)-(n-1)\}]=$

$\frac {n^2}4[\{2n\}\{2\}]=$

$\frac {n^2}4\cdot 4n = n^3$.

And ... that's that.

....

If somehow that doesn't *feel* right..... you can expand...

$\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac {(n-1)^2n^2}4=$

$\frac {n^2 (n^2 + 2n + 1)}4 -\frac {n^2(n^2 -2n+1)}4 = $

... and, yeah, yeah, we get it.